# How to round values of nested documents fields

Tags: mongodb

Given the collection:

```
db.temperatures.insertMany( [
  {
    "city": "New York",
    "readings": [
      { "temp": 32.232, "period": "morning" },
      { "temp": 35.1232, "period": "afternoon" },
      { "temp": 30, "period": "evening" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "city": "Rio",
    "readings": [
      { "temp": 32, "period": "morning" },
      { "temp": 35.1232, "period": "afternoon" },
      { "temp": 30, "period": "evening" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "city": "Sampa",
    "readings": [
      { "temp": 32.123123, "period": "morning" },
      { "temp": 35.1232, "period": "afternoon" },
      { "temp": 30, "period": "evening" }
    ]
  }
] )
```

How to round the `temp` field to 2 decimal places for documents where "period" is "morning":

I've tried these two commands:

```
db.temperatures.updateMany(
  { "readings": { $elemMatch: { "period": "morning", "temp": { $exists: true } } } },
  { $set: { "readings.$.temp": { $round: [ "$readings.$.temp", 2 ] } } },
)
```

```
db.temperatures.updateMany(
  { "readings.period": "morning" },
  { $set: { "readings.$[element].temp": { $round: [ "$readings.$[elment].temp", 2 ] } } },
  { arrayFilters: [ { "element.period": "morning", "element.temp": { $exists: true } } ] }
)
```

Both give me this error:

```
MongoServerError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$round' in 'readings.0.temp.$round' is not valid for storage.
```

Comment: $round is an aggregation operator, not an update operator

Answer (score 1):

As `temp` is at sub-array level, you will need to iterate through the array through `$map` to use `$round`

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "readings": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$readings",
          "as": "r",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$r",
              {
                "temp": {
                  $cond: {
                    if: {
                      $eq: [
                        "morning",
                        "$$r.period"
                      ]
                    },
                    then: {
                      "$round": [
                        "$$r.temp",
                        2
                      ]
                    },
                    else: "$$r.temp"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Nn99tlck8Nv)

Comment: This will round all readings, not just the morning ones

Comment: @Joe good catch. Thanks and updated the answer